# Magento 2.0 REST API Oauth Token Request Error

Tags: rest, api, oauth, magento2

Trying to integrate magento 2.0 with a desktop application (i.e the desktop application should be able to create products & download orders) using the REST API.

I am trying to make a '**POST**' call to Magento 2.0 token request to get the access token, however I am getting an error while sending the request: `oauth_problem=Consumer+key+has+expired`.

I am trying to generate the signature using:

```
POSThttp://xxxxxx/magento/oauth/token/request?oauth_nonce=cyzHawrmnCYz7cJT&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1474899965&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxx
```